# "This frame was blocked because it contains some insecure content." works on my computer, not others

Tags: facebook, iframe, blocked

I created an iframe Facebook app for use on my  FB page. I get this error "This frame was blocked because it contains some insecure content." I can see my page render correctly on my main computer, I sent the link to a friend, and they get an error. Also on another computer in my house I tried and got the error. Is it permissions, does it have to do with tokens, or something?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that certain iFrames will only work on the same domain to avoid someone injecting malicious code (cross-domain is a common problem also with ajax..)

Comment: How do I correct this? Any suggestions antogg2004? Because now, I get the same result, no matter what I try. Do I have to add Facebook code to my website? or change a Facebook setting within the app?

Comment: The problem is with SSL, I have a SSL version of the site , and it  working now =) , thanx for the help antogg2004

Answer (score 0):

Cross-domain iframe problems only occur if you attempt to use javascript to access a frame on another domain.

But this sounds like a different problem anyway, there must be an image or a script on your page that is accessing a non-secure asset. I use Safari's Activity window to drill down and find non-secure items that your page may be referring to. It's quite likely that you have an external script or stylesheet pulling in a non-secure asset.

Comment: I solved it, it was SSL , I had to use a different URL, for the Canvas page, it was <http:// www.example.com> , and for the Secure Canvas page it was <https:// example.netfirms.com> using SSL , but I have started to use Google Chrome to as u say drill down to the divs, and what not. Thanx for the post ice cream.